# Is there a way to enumerate files by creation time on an SMB share?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, smb

I'm looking for a way to retrieve files newer than a certain date/time on an SMB remote share, all working under Windows.  I've been using `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()`, and filtering as they are returned.  Unfortunately, this means every file record is being sent over the network before I look at it, and as the file list grows, this gets progressively worse.

I'm stuck working with a third party vendor such that I don't have the option of removing old files, and I can't run any code on the file server I'm reading from.

I've been able to get some temporary improvement by p/invoking `FindFirstFileEx`/`FindNextFile` and using the `FindExInfoBasic` and `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH` flags, but ideally, I'd like to offload the datetime filter to the server and only send the file records I need over the network.  Is there some API I'm just not finding that could help?

Comment: fs support filter only by name mask but not by time. you can yet bit improve by direct call `NtQueryDirectoryFile`

Comment: @RbMm, That is what it looks like.  Unfortunately, so much of the time is lost in the network lag, that anything that doesn't address the number of round trips won't make a significant difference.  What takes less than a second to enumerate on a local drive takes multiple hours over this network.

Comment: `NtQueryDirectoryFile` compare `FindFirstFileExW` have 2 advantages - `FindFirstFileExW` always do 1 extra call to `NtQueryDirectoryFile` and main - with `NtQueryDirectoryFile` you can control buffer size - large buffer - more files in buffer, less call count. if you need filter by time - you probably need have self agent on server side and send query to this agent

Comment: Thanks - I'll see what I can do with that!

Comment: In your `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()` are you sure you were writing the full query command? Because I suppose when you query a source, the source only returns elements matching the query and not everything.

Comment: Take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-enumerate-directories-and-files or are you trying to do something different?

Comment: @Tavershima, yes, the EnumerateFiles call I was using works perfectly fine locally, and even over a local network drive.  It just falls apart when the network link is slower.

Comment: Can you map the drive and use PowerShell? Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)}

Comment: @ThomasKoelle and what PowerShell can give you ? anyway **any** method internally will be use *NtQueryDirectoryFile[Ex]*. as result nothing can be faster that *NtQueryDirectoryFile[Ex]*

Comment: Actually few ways. 1) Using file name pattern, ask 3rd party to include date in it. That way you know the file names, hence no discovery needed, you can always work with small subset. 2) If you don't write to those files. Track the folder for updates (cheap network call), you can track size, or update date for folder. Along with that call you also get file list (no sorting yet), and cache the response. When during the next cycle you receive another list you have the diff of file list. Now all you gonna need is fetch files from the diff locally. And do whatever magic you need. 3) Combine 1&2

Answer (score 0):

The SMB protocol itself allows to create a [SMB2 QUERY_DIRECTORY Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-smb2/10906442-294c-46d3-8515-c277efe1f752) which gets answered with a [SMB2 QUERY_DIRECTORY Response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-smb2/4f75351b-048c-4a0c-9ea3-addd55a71956). According to the SMB protocol specification, you should be able to get a list of files of a directory, containing only the minimal set of information you need ("FileInformationClass") and transmitting them in large chunks.

To get an idea of how to implement it, I would take a look at the source code of [SharpCifs.Std](http://sharpcifsstd.dobes.jp/).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
DirectoryInfo DirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\archives1\library\");

DateTime StartOf2009 = new DateTime(2009, 01, 01);

// LINQ query for all files created before 2009.
var files = from f in DirInfo.EnumerateFiles()
       where f.CreationTimeUtc < StartOf2009
       select f;

// Show results.
foreach (var f in files)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0}", f.Name);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that you're still enumerating files, and that's exactly what Eclipse is trying to avoid.

Comment: I would love for this to work and the Linq query to back-propagate to the source machine, but this still fetches every file info record before it even starts to filter by time.